# mysql partition with no primary key

Tags: mysql, partitioning, partition

I'm studying partitions, and I'm wondering what's different about the two situations.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id   INT      NOT NULL,
    birthYear DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, birthYear
)) PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(birthYear)) (
    PARTITION p1970 VALUES LESS THAN (1980),
    PARTITION p1980 VALUES LESS THAN (1990),
    PARTITION p1990 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
    PARTITION p2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
    PARTITION pMaxValue VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    );
------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id   INT      NOT NULL,
    birthYear DATETIME NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(birthYear)) (
    PARTITION p1970 VALUES LESS THAN (1980),
    PARTITION p1980 VALUES LESS THAN (1990),
    PARTITION p1990 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
    PARTITION p2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
    PARTITION pMaxValue VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    );
```

The first is the partition in the presence of pk, and the second is the partition created without using pk.
I know the key and index are not generated in the second case, but can you tell me if the second case is generated but wrong or if it's a bad way to use it?

I used a translator so it might sound a little weird sorry thank you!

Comment: *I know the key and index are not generated in the second case* In InnoDB the primary key is present always. If there is no explicit PK or an index which may be used as PK then PK by 6-byte hidden inner row identifier is used.

Comment: (The PK does not make much difference.)  More importantly, there is probably _no_ benefit in partitioning your example table.  See: [_Partitioning_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)